# How do I change default ringtone in Skype?

Tags: skype

How do I change the default ringtone in Skype?

In some old versions I was able to replace the sound files in the `/usr/share/skype/sounds/`

Now the Skype folder [on my system] is `/usr/share/skypeforlinux/`, but I can not find any sound files there!

They are not in the `/usr/share/sounds/`, either

The default file ***was*** named `CallRingingIn.wav`

My system is Linux Mint

The default ringtone is nerve-wrecking and soul-killing

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype for Linux as of September 2023 is an Electron based application which has all the resources built-in. It seems like the only way to change its sounds is the application options. If it has none, it's unlikely you could do anything.

```
chrome_100_percent.pak
chrome_200_percent.pak
chrome_crashpad_handler
chrome-sandbox
icudtl.dat
libEGL.so
libffmpeg.so
libGLESv2.so
libvk_swiftshader.so
libvulkan.so.1
LICENSES.chromium.html
resources
resources.pak
skypeforlinux
snapshot_blob.bin
v8_context_snapshot.bin
version
vk_swiftshader_icd.json
```

Comment: Thank you. Sad... (And, there are no options in the menu to change the default sound, either...)

Comment: Microsoft used to have a special website where you can offer ideas for their software, maybe there's one for Skype as well. If it exists, you could pitch them this idea.

Comment: I've found the website: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/c3d06609-331c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472 People have asked for this feature multiple times already: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/search/c3d06609-331c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472?q=ringtone You could vote for this one: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/71e7ff42-bf04-ed11-a81b-6045bd864d4f but it looks like Microsoft isn't interested at all.